# Juego de mecanografia en c como hacer game over?

Tags: c

Este codigo trata sobre un juego de mecanografia para mi proyecto final de programacion pero estoy en la parte final de game over pero realmente no encuento la forma de como hacerlo por este lado estare dejando el codigo ayuda por favor!!!

De tal manera si se le puede hacer un cambio es eceptable de igual forma dicho cambio quisiera saber como y por que!

de ante mano mil gracias al que lo resuelva!

Les dare un poco de detalles que es lo que estoy haciendo para poder crear la funcion de game over si se fijan en el bucle en donde se ejecuta todo esta la variable w_l la cual deberia decir si perdiste o ganaste la cual creo que deberia funcionar cuando llegue a la linea que estoy imprimiendo pero nose como decirle al programa que ah llegado ahi!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<windows.h>
#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ((clock_t)(1000))
char matriz[5],c=0;
int v=0,x=0,y=0,fila=0;
int tiempo=0,aumento=0;
int cont=0;
int w_l=0;
int level=0;
struct base
{
  char c[5]
}letras[50];

void golpe(){
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
if (c==letras[aumento].c[i])
{
  letras[aumento].c[i]='\0';
  dibujo();

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
  if (letras[aumento].c[i]=='\0')
  {
      cont++;
      if (cont==5)
  {
      cont=0;
      aumento++;
  }

  }
  } 
}

}
cont=0;
}
void loop(){

do
{
if (kbhit()==1)
{
c=getch();
golpe();
}
if (v==1)
{
v=0;
dibujo(fila);
}

if ((tiempo/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)==level)
{
fila++;
tiempo=0;
v=1;
}
tiempo++;


} while (w_l<=0);

}
void dibujo(){
  y++;
  system("cls");
  int j=fila;
 for ( j = fila; j>=0; j--)
 {
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  x+=3;
  gotoxy(x,y);
  printf("%c  ",letras[j].c[i]);
}
y++;
x=3;
 }
if (y==15)
{
//w_l=1;
}
y=0;
x=3;
y=15;
x=0;
gotoxy(x,y);
printf("-------------------------------------");
x=3;y=0;
clock();
}
void carga(){
  int j=0;
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i <50;j++)
{ 
  if (j==5)
  {
      i++;
      j=-1;
  }
  v=1 +rand()%((2+1)-1);
         if (v==1)
         {
            c='a'+rand()%26;
         }
         else
         {
             c='A'+rand()%26;
         }
 for (int j = 0; j <5; j++)
 {
     if (letras[i].c[j]==c)
     {
        v=1 +rand()%((2+1)-1);
         if (v==1)
         {
            c='a'+rand()%26;
            j=-1;
         }
         else
         {
             c='A'+rand()%26;
             j=-1;
         }   
     }
 }
 letras[i].c[j]=c;
}
}
void gotoxy(int c,int y){  
    HANDLE hcon;  
    hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);  
    COORD dwPos;  
    dwPos.X = x;  
    dwPos.Y= y;  
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);  
} 
int main(){
  printf("Elige el level:\n\n1.Noob\n2.Principiante\n3.PRO\nopcion:");
  scanf("%i",&level);
switch (level)
{
case 1:
level=150;
break;
case 2:
level=50;
break;
default:
level=25;
  break;
}
carga();
dibujo(fila);
loop();
printf("\n");
if (w_l==0)
{
  printf("Has ganado!");
}
else
{
  printf("Has perdido!");
}
system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si esto te puede ayudar, pero este bucle:

```
do
{
if (kbhit()==1)
{
c=getch();
golpe();
}
if (v==1)
{
v=0;
dibujo(fila);
}

if ((tiempo/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)==level)
{
fila++;
tiempo=0;
v=1;
}
tiempo++;


} while (w_l<=0);
```

no tiene dentro de él ninguna instrucción para que se pueda salir de él.
Quiero decir, que se va a estar repitiendo mientas `w_l <= 0`, pero no se modifica `w_l` dentro del bucle.